# stripe number of time customer is charged for a plan

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to limit the number of times the user is charged for a plan. For example if the user is already charged 3 times for a plan, I want to cancel his subscription so he not charged again.

Can I get the count of number of times the user has been charged for particular subscription for a particular stripe customer through code?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this is to just count, either in my own database or in metadata how many times the customer has been charged and then cancel the subscription once my count reaches the maximum.